# NSNumber initialization issue

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, nsnumber

Recently I found interesting problem connected with NSNumber initialization.

The difference occurred between simulator (9.3.1) and device (9.3.1).

Let assume that we've got int x = 2;
Now we're initializing NSNumber and passing it to a method.

```
NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.x];
[self.method setTestNumber: test];
```

This two lines had a correct result on both simulator and device.

**BUT**
using only this line

```
[self.method setTestNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.x]];
```

had quite unexpected result. Running it on simulator NSNumber intValue was equal to 2.

Running it on device had incorrect random value. How is that possible? Device is iPad 4 A1458. Also tested on iPad 3 16GB. The same problem occurred. Can you verify this problem?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. It would be helpful to see how your "method" class looks like and how you initilize it.

Comment: write your `setTestNumber` method. Problem should be there in that method

Comment: What do you mean by "simulator (9.3.1)"?  We haven't released an iOS 9.3.1 simulator runtime.  I assume you mean with iOS 9.3?

Comment: I can't post exactly this method because of NDA. Yes I mean simulator 9.3 my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will actually optimize those two codepaths to the exact same asm.  There is no difference between them.

Comment: I will reproduce it later and post exact code/github repo + screenshots showing this effect on side-project. I can't post exact code now because of NDA.